# Cucumber Test not working - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Scenario:

```
Feature: Login Success

  Scenario: Login in  User
    Given I am on the sign_in page
    And I fill in "Email" with "test@gmail.com"
    And I fill in "Password" with "12345678"
    When I press "Sign in"
    Then page should have content "Update Projects"
```

I am using devise.

Steps:

```
Given /^I am on the sign_in page$/ do
  visit ('/users/sign_in')
end

Given /^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1, arg2|
  fill_in arg1, :with => arg2
end

When /^I press "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  click_button arg1
end

Then /^page should have content "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  expect(page).to have_content arg1
end
```

Quite simple. I am using devise.

Why does it fail:

> expected to find text "Update Projects" in...

Why is cucumber not redirecting to the next page?